# reduce mongo db query to pure array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

when i run `db.abhishek.em.find({})` I have

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac62d35b075e574b3e7eeaa"), "name" : "first", "employed" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac62d3fb075e574b3e7eeab"), "name" : "second", "employed" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac62d4eb075e574b3e7eeac"), "name" : "third", "employed" : false }
```

I want to reduce this result into an array of simple object ids like this by adding or chaining something to find function , something like 
db.a.b.find({employed:true}).somefunction() which can return the below array
I want to use the command nested with $in in a bigger query to achieve some sort of relational querying

```
[
ObjectId("5ac62d35b075e574b3e7eeaa"),
ObjectId("5ac62d3fb075e574b3e7eeab")
]
```

***-----------------EDIT----------------------***

For an example case I want to get employed employees by running

```
db.abhishek.another.find({id:{$in:db.abhishek.em.find({employed:true},{_id:1}).toArray()}})
```

or something similiar as this command is not working

The db.a.another collection is

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac63de1b075e574b3e7eead"), "id" : ObjectId("5ac62d35b075e574b3e7eeaa"), "name" : "Lets say person 1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac63df7b075e574b3e7eeae"), "id" : ObjectId("5ac62d3fb075e574b3e7eeab"), "name" : "Lets say person 2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac63e06b075e574b3e7eeaf"), "id" : ObjectId("5ac62d4eb075e574b3e7eeac"), "name" : "Lets say person 3" }
```

***-----------------EDIT----------------------***
Solved see my answer below

Comment: you might want to use `toArray()`.

Comment: `I want to use the command nested with $in in a bigger query to achieve some sort of relational querying` -> What do you really want?

Comment: toArray gives me the complete array of objects (each bieng the complete object), i just want an array of Object ids and no further nesting to use it within $in

Comment: Try `db.abhishek.em.find({}, {_id:1})`

Comment: @jonas-w I basically want to use something like 

db.a.c.find({_id:{$in:db.a.b.find{employed:true}.somemethod_thatworkswith$in}})

Comment: Your example case seems a bit pointless, as your first query is returning the exact same documents your second one would if it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for providing directions and suggestions to move forward,
I was able to successfully do some sort of relational based query using the following

```
db.abhishek.another.find({id:{$in:db.abhishek.em.find({employed:true},{_id:1}).map(function(e) {return e._id})}},{name:1,_id:0})
```

It gave this as output

```
{ "name" : "Lets say person 1" }
{ "name" : "Lets say person 2" }
```

This query took all records from em collection with employed set to true,form its array and then pass it to $in operator on query for "another" collection to give output

toArray method used to convert objects nested in array hence failing $in operator

Thanks @veeram for telling about selection of fields

Answer (score 2):

Use MongoDB to only provide those fields from the model. In MongoDB terms this is called Projection. There is a MongoDB method `.project()` that you can chain onto your query like this:

```
db.abhishek.em.find({}).project({});
```

that should do it. If you want to explicit exclude fields, you do:

```
db.abhishek.em.find({}).project({name:0, employed:0});
```

then, finally, to get the output in array form do:

```
db.abhishek.em.find({}).project({name:0, employed:0}).toArray();
```

Reference here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: it cannot find project method,what could have gone wrong?

Comment: The implementations differ per platform. The example I gave was for MongoDB from NodeJS. What platform are you using? In the reference I provided above, click the **tab at the top of the page** that corresponds do your platform.